# C++ ADL of a function in another namespace

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

I have a function template `printSize` calling the overloaded function `getSize` before `getSize` is declared. For a clearer structure of my program, I would like to put both functions in different namespaces `A` and `B`, as the commented code lines show. However, ADL will then fail to find `getSize`.

Actually, `printSize` and `getSize` are implemented in different header files. Therefore, I cannot put a `using namespace` directive.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace A {

template <typename T> struct tag {};

template <typename T>
void printSize(const T &data)
{
    size_t data_size = getSize(data, tag<T>{});
    //size_t data_size = B::getSize(data, tag<T>{});
    std::cout << "Size: " << data_size << std::endl;
}

//} // namespace A

//namespace B {

constexpr size_t getSize(const int &, tag<int>)
{
    return sizeof(int);
}

size_t getSize(const std::string &str, tag<std::string>)
{
    return str.size();
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t getSize(const std::array<T, N> &array, tag<std::array<T, N>>)
{
    size_t array_size = 0;
    for (const T &element : array)
        array_size += getSize(element, tag<T>{});
    return array_size;
}

} // namespace A/B

int main()
{
    int a;
    A::printSize(a);

    std::array<std::string, 2> arr = {{"foo", "foobar"}};
    A::printSize(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to make this code compile with `printSize` and `getSize` being defined in different namespaces?

Comment: By prefixing them with the namespace name? As you do in the commented out statement in `printSize`? And of course make sure the declarations of the functions are available before you attempt to use them.

Comment: I think both approaches won't work. The user of this library might provide additional overloads of `getSize` that might be defined after including the header files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to put the tag into the `B` namespace, and pull it into `A`.

```
namespace B {
    template <typename T> struct tag {};
}

namespace A {
   using B::tag;
}
```

Now, because `tag` comes from the `B` namespace, it will associate `B` for ADL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `using` declaration to introduce a name from another namespace. For example:

```
template <typename T>
void printSize(const T &data)
{
    using B::getSize;
    std::size_t data_size = getSize(data, tag<T>{});
    std::cout << "Size: " << data_size << std::endl;
}
```

`getSize` depends on a template parameter `T`, so ADL will be used in the second phase of lookup (when this template is instantiated) to find other `getSize`s provided by the user. Here `B::getSize` should be declared before `printSize` and `tag` itself seems to be redundant.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. g++ fails with `error: ‘B::getSize’ has not been declared`.

Comment: @Dino, `B::getSize` should be declared before `printSize`.